# Why Apple Created isBatteryMonitoringEnabled?

Tags: swift, battery, uidevice

To monitor battery state and level, app should first enable `isBatteryMonitoringEnabled` property and set it `true`.

But why this property created?

You can set it to `false` or `true` wherever you want and system does not interfere in monitoring ever.

Is there any advantages in performance to set it `false`?

Comment: I'm not sure how performance wise is it, but if you'll start listening to stuff you don't really need, Apple might not accept your application (the default value is `false` btw)

Comment: Apple didn't say about rejecting apps that use it and also [documented it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620045-isbatterymonitoringenabled)

Answer (score 0):

I think the OS wants to know what's is your app needs. It affects which apps should be terminated when there isn't enough memory.